# Dynamically add text strings with increasing number to a div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying add some text strings with increasing number to a div,
for example:

```
<div>
Text String n°: 1
Text String n°: 2
Text String n°: 3
etc...
</div>
```

but somethings does not work properly:

```
var StringsContainer = document.getElementById('StringsContainer');

var createTextStrings = function(){   
var i = 0
    while(i < 3){   

        i++;
        console.log("String n°:" + (i + 1));    
        document.body.innerText = "String n°:" + (i + 1);
    }    
};   

createTextStrings();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5z6K/

In the console.log I can see a similar result, but it still not works.

---

Solution:
Here updated perfect result wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5z6K/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change append the string:

```
document.body.innerText += "String n°:" + (i) +"\n";
```

Full code:

```
var StringsContainer = document.getElementById('StringsContainer');

var createTextStrings = function () {
    var i = 0
    while (i < 4) {
        i++;
        console.log("String n°:" + (i));
        document.body.innerText += "String n°:" + i + "\n";
    }
};

createTextStrings();
```

Also, you don't need `i + 1` as i is already incremented.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5z6K/1/

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the strings as you are looping:

```
document.body.innerText += "String n°:" + i + "\n";
```

Plus, you don't need to i++ then adding another i +1 when displaying it. So, just drop the +1 on the string display.

UPDATED: adding "\n" for the line change.

See the fiddle at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yd5YG/3/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out:** http://jsfiddle.net/Y5z6K/2/

**JS:**

```
var StringsContainer = document.getElementById('StringsContainer');

var createTextStrings = function () {
    var i = 0
    while (i < 3) {
        console.log("String n°:" + (i + 1));
        document.body.innerHTML += "String n°:" + (i + 1) + "<br\>";
        i++;
    }
};

createTextStrings();
```